# Field 'id' expected a number but got <property object at 0x03F53528>. -

Tags: django, django-views, foreign-keys, slug

I am building a registration app that needs to register people based on the specific User model instance. My urls are based on the slugs of my users and based on those values people can register at a specific user. For example, people can register at Apples or at Bananas. The form that is posted contains the specific user.id which is passed to the People Model alongside the filled in form fields.

Now I am getting the following error which I can't get my head around:

*Field 'id' expected a number but got <property object at 0x03CC54B0>.*

My urls:

```
app_name = 'register'

urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug>/contact/', ContactView.as_view(), name='contact'),
    path('<slug>/thanks/', ThanksView.as_view(), name='thanks'),
]
```

My models:

```
class Bedrijf(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    bedrijfsnaam = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=30)

class Bezoeker(models.Model):
    bedrijf = models.ForeignKey(Bedrijf, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    voornaam = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    achternaam = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

My Views

```
class ContactView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'register/contact.html'
    form_class = BezoekerForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('bedankt', kwargs={'slug': Bedrijf.slug})

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = BezoekerForm
        slug = get_object_or_404(Bedrijf, slug=Bedrijf.slug)
        context = {'form': form, 'slug': slug}
        return render(self, self.template_name, context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        bedrijf = Bedrijf.objects.get(pk=Bedrijf.pk)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = self.form_class(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                new_register = form.save(commit=False)
                new_register.bedrijf = bedrijf.pk
                new_register.save()
            return reverse('bedankt')
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query `Bedrijf.objects.get(pk=Bedrijf.pk)` does not make much sense, since `Bedrijf` is the class, so `Bedrijf.pk` is just a property.

You can make use of `get_object_or_404` to retrieve the corresponding `Bedrijf`, for the `slug` URL parameter:

```
class ContactView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'register/contact.html'
    form_class = BezoekerForm

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = BezoekerForm()
        slug = self.kwargs['slug']
        bedrijf = get_object_or_404(Bedrijf, slug=slug)
        context = {'form': form, 'slug': slug}
        return render(self, self.template_name, context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        slug = self.kwargs['slug']
        bedrijf = get_object_or_404(Bedrijf, slug=slug)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = self.form_class(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.instance.bedrijf = bedrijf
                form.save()
            return reverse('bedankt', slug=slug)
        return render(self, self.template_name, {'slug': slug, 'form': form})
```

But this actually does all the work itself. One uses class-based views like a `CreateView` to remove a lot of boilerplate code:

```
class ContactView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'register/contact.html'
    form_class = BezoekerForm

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context.update(
            slug=self.kwargs['slug'],
            bedrijf = get_object_or_404(Bedrijf, slug=slug)
        )
        return context

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('bedankt', kwargs={'slug': self.object.bedrijf.slug})

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.bedrijf = get_object_or_404(Bedrijf, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thank you sir for the extensive and in depth answer. This made me realize I had a lot of boilerplate code and showed me a way to fix this. Dived into the Django docs and I am understanding the get_context_data, get_succes_url and form_valid methods of class based views a lot better now.

I tweaked your example a bit because the slug in get_context_data was not defined.

*bedrijf = get_object_or_404(Bedrijf, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])* did the trick. I am now only asking myself if the slug = self.kwargs['slug'] above this is boilerplate code?

In the get_success_url method it was saying that there was no reverse for 'bedankt'. Fixed this by specifying the app_name in front of it like:

*return reverse('register:bedankt', kwargs={'slug': self.object.bedrijf.slug})*